# Sending a message using Azure Service bus from an Angular App returns Cors error

Tags: angular, azure, azureservicebus, angular-universal, angular8

```js
sendLogs() {
    const token = this.getAuthHeader('url', 'syslogsmicroqueue', 'accesskeyhere');
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(`Authorization : ${token}`),
      body: {
        log_name: 'sample',
        params:
          { birthdate: 'sample',
            contentCategory: 'sample',
            contentId: 'sample',
            fullName: 'sample',
            ipAddress: 'sample',
            kapamilyaName: 'sample',
            location: 'sample',
            screenName: 'sample',
            userEntitlement: 'sample',
            videoGenre: 'sample',
            videoTitle: 'sample',
            world: ''
          },
        platform: 'web',
        uid: 'sample'
      }
    };

    return this.http.post('https://service-name.servicebus.windows.net/systemlogs_queue/messages', options);
  }

  getAuthHeader(resourceUri: string, keyName: string, key: string) {
    const d = new Date();
    const sinceEpoch = Math.round(d.getTime() / 1000);

    const expiry = (sinceEpoch + 3600);
    const stringToSign = encodeURIComponent(resourceUri) + '\n' + expiry;
    const hash = crypto.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, key);
    const hashInBase64 = crypto.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);

    const sasToken = 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encodeURIComponent(resourceUri) + '&sig=' + encodeURIComponent(hashInBase64) + '&se=' + expiry + '&skn=' + keyName;
    console.log(sasToken);

    return sasToken;
  }
```

I am using Angular Universal host with Azure service, now I am trying to send system logs per user in Azure Service Bus but it keeps on return CORS Policy Errors. I've read about this [blog](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/55b02292-b268-4a72-a63a-f3ad88c6dda3/is-there-a-cors-setting-for-azure-service-bus-queues?forum=servbus) and apparently suggested to do Azure Logic Apps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus) which I don't have any access. What I've really pursuing is to have a way without doing the Azure Logic Apps (which again I don't have the access).

Maybe someone out there tried and solved this problem :)

I've tried to install [@azure/service-bus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus) or [azure-sb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-sb) which I'm seeing to be used only in server-side and not in angular app.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://name-of-service-bus.servicebus.windows.net/systemlogs_queue/messages' from origin 'https://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Could you show the code you are trying to use? If you have a service bus access key in there by the way, the approach is wrong and the key will leak to everyone using your app.

Comment: I've added the code @juunas

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, I'd say Service Bus doesn't want you calling them from front-end code.

Putting your access key there is a bad idea as anyone can get the key.

You might need to do the message sending in a back-end and call the back-end from your front-end.

Comment: Upon reading the docu for azure service bus, it is open for any IP that will access it in terms of CORS policy, but I guess it doesn't allow web platform to do the call. I have this api for service bus queue only so it means I need to do it directly as well. And the backend will have the key instead